# Crop SVG from left & right sides

Tags: css, html, svg, responsive-design

Sorry, I couldn't find any existing information on this that didn't require the viewbox to be manually changed.

I have an inline SVG which spans across the full width of a webpage (1920px wide by default) and I was wondering if there is a way I could crop the image instead of it scaling down (I understand this is one of the major points of using SVG)

The image in question needs to not scale down as I've embedded a PNG image inside the SVG, the reason for this is because I'm using SVG as a responsive image map.

I found it really hard to even explain what I'm trying to achieve so diagram time (sorry!), I'm hoping it's just a case of Monday brain and the solution is easier than I think.

[image: diagram]

Comment: If you want it to remain the same size but crop, don't use a viewBox on the outer <svg> element.

Comment: Nice illustration, makes the question easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the `viewBox` attribute, but if you set the `width` and `height` attributes on your SVG, it will keep its size and not shrink with the container. To center the SVG in the containing `<div>` you need to apply a little trick, which is setting the `left` CSS property to `50%` and then use `transform: translate(-50%, 0)` to shift it back. Also, the SVG must have `position: absolute` and the container `position: relative` set.

Here is a working example:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg width="800" height="160" viewBox="0 0 1000 200">  
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="200" fill="teal" />
    <circle cx="500" cy="100" r="50" fill="goldenrod" />
  </svg>
</div>
```